# Is it good to delegate event handling to events, when using flutter bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, event-handling, bloc, flutter-bloc

I started to learn bloc state management recently, and my mapEventToState often getting too large, so i split event handling to another async* methods, for example:

```
class ClassNameBloc extends Bloc<ClassNameEvent, ClassNameState> {
  ClassNameBloc(): super(ClassNameInitialState());
  
  Stream<ClassNameStata> handleEventOne() async* {
    yield ClassNameState; 
    ...
  }

  @override
  Stream<ClassNameState> mapEventToState(ClassNameEvent event) async* {
    if (event is ClassNameEvent1) {
      yield* handleEventOne();
    } else if (...) {
      yield ClassNameState;
      ...
    }
  }
  
  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    super.close();
  }
}
```

But using this solution does not fix problem of large if else statements

So another solution is to delegate event handling to events, for example

```
class ClassNameEvent extends Equatable {
  Stream<ClassNameState> handleEvent(HandleEventParams) async* {}
  
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Each concrete event overrides handleEvent method, so in bloc i can type

```
class ClassNameBloc extends Bloc<ClassNameEvent, ClassNameState> {
  ClassNameBloc(): super(ClassNameInitialState());
  
  @override
  Stream<ClassNameState> mapEventToState(ClassNameEvent event) async* {
    yield* event.handleEvent();
  }
  
  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    super.close();
  }
}
```

I know, that its not a very good approach of event-handling, because event's main function is to notify listener about event, not handle itself

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer with the truth, but I can provide some context.

Bloc library [advices](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=bloc-vs-redux) that:

> BLoC is a design pattern that is defined by the following rules:
>
> - Input and Output of the BLoC are simple Streams and Sinks.
> - Dependencies must be injectable and Platform agnostic.
> - No platform branching is allowed.
> - Implementation can be whatever you want as long as you follow the above rules.

I read all https://bloclibrary.dev and couldn't find some preferences for your question. But looking at the [examples on GitHub](https://github.com/felangel/Bloc/blob/master/examples), I feel the event handling is in the Bloc class, not in the Event class.